# how to serialize and deserialize nested xml containing seperators

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I am under a situation that i have xml like this in a string :

```
string xmlString =
<parameters>
    <parameter>
        <name>name1</name>
        <label>Max1</label>
        <unit>Millions1</unit>
        <component>
            <type>Combo</type>
            <attributes>
                <type>Integer1</type>
                <displayed>41</displayed>
                <selected>01</selected>
                <items>
                    <item>51</item>
                    <item>11</item>
                    <item>21</item>
                    <item>51</item>
                </items>
            </attributes>
        </component>
    </parameter>

    <separator>Auto Skewing</separator>

    <parameter>
        <name>name2</name>
        <label>Max2</label>
        <unit>Millions2</unit>
        <component>
            <type>Combo</type>
            <attributes>
                <type>Integer2</type>
                <displayed>42</displayed>
                <selected>02</selected>
                <items>
                    <item>5</item>
                    <item>12</item>
                    <item>22</item>
                    <item>52</item>
                </items>
            </attributes>
        </component>
    </parameter>
</parameters>
```

Here i have to render the GUI (UIElements) using Combo Bow which will look like this:

[image]
**First how to Serialize this xml i just need help in Parameters class rest i can do myself ?**
I can deserialize it very easily by doing so:

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parameters));
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlstring));
Parameters parameters = (Parameters)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

But the problem is after this step i have to render GUI using Converter() of IValueConverter() doing something like this :

```
 ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
        TextBox txtblk2 = new TextBox();
        #region IValueConverter Members
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            ICollection<Parameter> list = value as ICollection<Parameter>;
            List<UIElement> result = new List<UIElement>();    
                if (list != null)
                {
                    foreach (Parameter p in list)
                    {                
                        if (p.Component.Type == "Combo")
                        {
                            StackPanel st = new StackPanel()
                            {
                                Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal                           
                            };

                            var txtblk = new TextBox();                           
                            txtblk.Text = p.Label;                           
                            foreach (var item in p.Component.Attributes.Items)
                            {
                                cb.Items.Add(item);  //These item contains a l0,15,45,60 to select through combo box   
                            }
                            cb.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(comboBox1_SelectionChanged);
                            cb.SelectedIndex = cb.Items.Count - 1;
                            txtblk2.Text = cb.SelectedValue.ToString() +" millions";
                            st.Children.Add(txtblk);
                            st.Children.Add(cb);      
                            txtblk2.FontSize = 18;                          
                            st.Children.Add(txtblk2);
                            result.Add(st);                       
                        }
                    }
                }
            return(result);
        }
```

**Now the question is how to draw this separator line (Auto Skewing in my xml) which will seperate the rendering of two seperate GUIs corresponding to two different GUIs(two different "Parameter" present in xml, Please see the snap shot to understand more) ?**

Answer (score 1):

`XmlSerializer` does not really expect interleaved data like this, and even if you successfully serialize the data into an object model, you will not be able to distinguish where the separator went. Your best bet would be to either load it into a DOM (`XmlElement` / `XElement`) and just loop over the elements, or use a transformation tool such as xslt (although that isn't very fashionable these days).

Comment: thanks for helping me but How to do that ? How to load it into DOM ? Could you please write any sample please to make as reference ? Would eb a big help.

Comment: @user234839 you may want to look at the `XElement` or `XmlDocument` pages on MSDN

Comment: let me try something then will come soon if any problem comes. But in my point of view i have problem in rendering GUI for seperators because after <separator> the next GUI must render in next row.(As you can see in my snapshot)

Comment: @user234839 well basically you just need to `foreach` over the elements

Comment: tahnks let me try will come back soon to mark you as answer as if it works.

Comment: In Parameters class do i need to do two times "        [XmlElement("parameter")]
        public Parameter Parameter { get;set;}" because there are two "parameters" ? How to manage here for two Parameter?

Comment: And what to do here for seperators ? Do i need to create class for them as well inside "Parameters" class ?

Comment: @user234839 taht is a UI question - nothing to do with the xml. You tell me: what do you need to do for separators?

Comment: I need your help in serializing the "Parameters" class of my xml. How and what to do for two nested parameters and seperators ? .

Comment: for Seperators will be used for seperating two UI (one for upper parameter and another for Lower Parameter like this : "<P>UI for first Parameter</P><S>Auto Skewing</S><P>UI for second Parameter</P>") . Here P is Parameter and S is Seperator